# glfwSetCharCallback not accepting my function signature

Tags: function, input, glfw, signature

Made a GLFW window. Trying to set up user input to it. I have "glfwSetCharCallback" being called with the (seemingly) correct arguments. The last argument is a function that should be called when a key is being pressed. I called it "callbackFun". "glfwSetCharCallback" will not be having any of it, telling me that "callbackFun" has the wrong function signature. What did I do wrong?

```
int MultiLauncher::run()
{
    std::cout << "Begin..." << std::endl;
    GLFWwindow* window = initApp();
    //character input
    glfwSetCharCallback(window, callbackFun);

    figure triangle;

    /* Game Loop until the user closes the window */
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window) && keepRunningGame)
    {

        /* Render here */
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        triangle.buildFigure();
        triangle.drawFigure();

        /* Swap front and back buffers */
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        /* Poll for and process events */
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}

void MultiLauncher::callbackFun(GLFWwindow* window, uint codepoint)
{
    std::cout << codepoint << std::endl;
    keyEventsInstance.processKey(codepoint);
}
```

Tried googling the correct function signature for callbackFun, it seems good, but glfwSetCharCallback won't accept it.

Comment: It is more a C++ topic than GLFW. I would recommend to include the C++ tag.

Comment: The [link](https://www.educba.com/c-plus-plus-vector-vs-c-plus-plus-array/) you commented on your now-deleted question is outright wrong about the performance difference.

Answer (score 0):

If `MultiLauncher::callbackFun` is not a static member function, then under the hood the signature looks something like

```
void MultiLauncher::callbackFun(MultiLauncher* this, GLFWwindow* window, uint codepoint);
```

which is not the expected function signature by GLFW.

Simply make the member function `static` (put the keyword `static` in front of the function declaration), e.g.

```
class MultiLauncher {
public:

    // static member function declaration
    static void callbackFun(GLFWwindow* window, uint codepoint);

};

// function definition
// there is no object (this) associated,
// so, if you need an object, you have to set it somewhere (accessible)
// before this function gets called
void MultiLaucher::callbackFun(GLFWwindow* window, uint codepoint)
{
    //...
}
```

More info:

- https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_functions
- https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static#Static_member_functions